# Find the rate of change. $P=250(1+(2t/(49+t^2)))$

Tags: derivatives

A population of bacteria is introduced into a culture. The number of bacteria $P$ can be modeled by $P=250(1+(2t/(49+t^2)))$ where $t$ is time (in hours). Find the rate of change of the population when $t=4.00$.

I know the first thing I need to do is find the derivative, but don't know where to start.

Comment: To clarify, are you having trouble taking $\frac{dP}{dt}$?

Comment: Yes. Should I be using quotient rule?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is useful first to simplify to $P=250+\frac{500t}{49+t^2}$.

Comment: That looks easier to differentiate.

Comment: That's why I did it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(t) = 250 \left( 1 + \frac{2t}{49+t^2} \right) = 250 + \frac{500t}{49+t^2}$$

To find the derivative, drop the constant term and apply the quotient rule:

$$P'(t) = \frac{(500t)'(49+t^2) - (500t)(49 + t^2)'}{(49+t^2)^2}$$

$$= \frac{500(49+t^2) - (500t)(2t)}{(49+t^2)^2}$$

Then plug in $t=4$.